# Relative Path - Visual Studio - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, relative-path

In App.config I have given this relative path for my file under the solution folder. I am using this relative path in a web application.

```
value="..\filename.log"/>
```

& also tried with

```
value="~/filename.log"/>
```

But it didn't worked, I then debugged the code and came to know that it is trying to find the file in this path

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE..

**SOLUTION**

Make sure that ~ doesn't works for relative path when it is a web application. So if you want to give the relative path in the web application, use below code.

```
string logFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFile"]);
```

Here "LogFile" is the key to the value "filename.log"

Comment: It should be `~/`

Comment: If the value is in an **app**.config file, then it isn't a web app and you can't use the tilde syntax.

Comment: Please edit your title so that it's not just the tags in a different order. See [ask] for more information on what a good question (and title) should contain.

Comment: _"it is trying to find this file in path where VS is installed"_ - no, it doesn't. Show how your application reads this value, how it uses it and how you came to that conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to find a folder relative to the executing code, you can use something like

```
var location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

...to get the executing code's current location.  You can then get the folder this way:

```
var directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(location);
```

You can them append a relative path using [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
var directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(location);
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "..\filename.log");
```

...which will yield an absolute path.

Comment: This is his app.config, it's basically a XML you cannot run C# in it

Comment: ^ What? Mr. Wu's answer is fine, he knows its an App.config file. The app.config file will not change. He means the way to **use** this relative path inside the code, which is basically converting it to an absolute path. Although, he also states its not a good idea to use relative paths, which I strongly disagree, there are obviously many scenarios where its the right thing to use.

Comment: If this is not a c# question then please remove the `c#` tag from the post.  I adjusted my answer to remove the opinionated bit.

Answer (score 1):

In your config File use `~/` to access the directory

```
value="~/filename.log"/>
```

You can use `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` or  `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` to get the Current Solution directory (working directory). So you can directly use this in your code to access that log file.

```
String path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"/filename.log";
```